# Can Angular change language at runtime?

Tags: angular, localization

I have checked the following possibilities to change languages:
i18n -- does not allow changing language at runtime, we have to build the app each time.
ngx-translate -- apparently allows changing language at runtime but might be deprecated
@angular/localize -- some posts suggests that it allows changing language at runtime, but I could not find any.

I am currently following this tutorial: https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular9-app-with-xlf-files, it makes use of @angular/localize module, but this still does not allow translation at runtime.

My question is: are there any library that allows the translation to be done at runtime? Can I use ngx-translate (is it deprecated or buggy)?

Comment: ngx-translate is not deprecated (where did you get that information?) you can use it but it is not the native angular way of doing it. The first part of your link does cover it pretty good. Ask yourself these questions and decide what to use.

Answer (score 7):

[@angular/localize](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#add-the-localize-package) is a part of the i18n that comes from Angular and with the package you need different builds in order to change the languages and there is reason behind it because how often will a user be changing the language? **So you can't do dynamically translations using it**. Also if you are doing Server Sider Rendering with [Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal) it's the proper way of translating the pages because otherwise the pages that you render won't show the text properly. You can check out this post about [ngx-translate and SSR](https://andremonteiro.pt/ngx-translate-angular-universal-ssr/).

Even inside the [post](https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular9-app-with-xlf-files) that you've shared you can see that it says: `You can't change the locale at runtime`

You can use [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core). If you check out the github repo you can see that **it's not deprecated**. And it's actually one of the most used libraries for translating angular apps dynamically.

I still prefer the default Angular i18n. Even though in one of our projects because it's really big we've created our own way of dynamically translating the text which is a mixture of using the standard i18n and a pipe.

Comment: Hello, how did you manage this standard i18n and a pipe? Do you have any example. Thanks.